# Karma unit test 'undefined' is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have a custom directive for checking if values in two input fields are equal to each other (repeat password) which I want to test. It works fine but test fails with this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'element.add(tween)')
```

The directive is very simple and straightforward:

```
angular.module('fmAppApp')
.directive('valueMatch', function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var tween = '#' + attrs.valueMatch;
        element.add(tween).on('keyup', function () {
          scope.$apply(function () {
            var v = element.val() === $(tween).val();
            ctrl.$setValidity('valueMatch', v);
          });
        });
   }
 };
```

});

And here is the spec:

```
describe('Directive: valueMatch', function () {

  // load the directive's module
  beforeEach(module('fmAppApp'));

  var element, origElement,
    scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
   scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should set change validity state of element depending on value of another element',
    inject(function ($compile) {
      origElement = $compile('<input id="orig">')(scope);
      element = $compile('<input value-match="orig" ng-model="repeat">')(scope);
      scope.$digest();
      expect(element.$valid).toBe(true);
      origElement.val('12345');
      scope.$digest();
      expect(element.$valid).toBe(false);
      element.val('12345');
      expect(element.$valid).toBe(true);
 }));
});
```

So apparently `add()` is undefined, right? But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in case of your unit test, Angular is loading jqLite instead of jQuery, which does not have `add` function.

Either use one of the jqlite compatible function described here https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/docs/api/angular.element

Or include jQuery too in your tests, in karma config.

Comment: actuallly I think you are right, but I have already changed my directive so that it won't need jQuery.